# Verification of the existence of defined SVN:Externals using python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, svn

I am in the process of setting up a process driven using Python scripts. The script performs a SVN checkout of a project and then creates a tag/release.

However the service account does not have access to certain portions of the Subversion repository.

Problem: When a tag/release is created for a check-out with the subversion external pinned, what i observe is that the tag gets created without throwing up any errors. However performing further operations on the created tag/release, I observe that due to errors in getting all the externals the process fails.

The problem is visible as "External failed" with a set of reasons when i try to do the checkout using TortoiseSVN.

Solution Requested: Is there a method to verify the existence(or permissions to access) of all the defined svn:externals before creation of the tag/release?

Answer (score 0):

> When a tag/release is created for a check-out with the subversion external pinned

I suppose, reason for further errors in not PEG-revisions in definitions, but relative paths, which become invalid after changing location of destination on tagging (TBT!)

Anyway, you can:

- get the whole list of externals for any tree by calling something like `svn propget svn:externals --recursive <ROOT OF TREE>`
- check access for every external resource by calling (and checking results, not exit-code) `svn ls <URL>` for external directories or `svn cat <URL>` for external files